# Dowloading dump image file of wikipedia

Tags: wikipedia

I'm trying to download image dump of wikipedia to put it in my local MediaWiki. Where is the place to download this please?

After googling, I don't see any simple answer. It will be also good if there is a way to only take thumbnail dump of these image.

Comment: What is your local copy used for? If you only want to show a copy of Wikipedia pages with thumbnails, you can use ZIM dumps in Kiwix (or kiwix-serve), which include images. http://www.kiwix.org/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the situation with file dumps is not very good. The latest dumps I could find are from December 2012. They [can be downloaded from your.org](http://ftpmirror.your.org/pub/wikimedia/imagedumps/tarballs/fulls/20121201/).

Though are you sure you want to download all that? The dumps for English Wikipedia put together take more than 2 TB, downloading that is going to take a while.

Comment: tank's for your answer.2TB is too big.I will what i can do.THE link taht you gave is the same that i found.I think it's the only place of that dump so the size makes me fear.PLease where is the right link in this page for french dump.I see http://ftpmirror.your.org/pub/wikimedia/imagedumps/tarballs/fulls/20121201/.frwiki-20121201-remote-media-4.tar.OnlSZW

Comment: PLease where is the right link in this page for french dump.I see http://ftpmirror.your.org/pub/wikimedia/imagedumps/tarballs/fulls/20121201/.frwiki-20121201-remote-media-4.tar.OnlSZW,frwiki-20121201-local-media-1.tar,frwiki-20121201-remote-media-1.tar,...,frwiki-20121201-remote-media-10.tar.I'm confuse.Sorry for the double post

Comment: @user2304712 Don't download the file that starts with a dot (`.frwiki`), only the files that start with `frwiki`.